# Upgrading from FEP4 to FEP6 - how long does it take?

Tags: websphere-commerce

Our customer has an existing store based on FEP4/Madisons migrated all the way from several major versions ago WCS. They want to transition to a new store based on Aurora. The logic project and front-end interaction with it is not up to date at all, so along the way we want to migrate that.

We are trying to make a rough plan for the project.

The other guys in the company (who are unavailable right now - great!) have told me that their experience is that while a FEP upgrade should only take about a week, it always end up taking at least a month.

I am trying to establish if there is a big time difference between these two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** "I want to upgrade an existing Madisons-based store and the associated WCS infrastructure and DB2 schema/data from FEP4 to FEP6" In this world we keep the existing development images and the various other servers along from dev to PROD, and upgrade the existing store + infrastructure to FEP6 before we start building the new store.

**Scenario 2:** "I want to create an entirely new store based on Aurora and the existing data for the old store, and upgrade the associated WCS infrastructure and DB2 schema/data from FEP4 to FEP6". In this world we create all new environments for dev ... prod, and so have a FEP4 branch for the current store, and a FEP6 branch for the new store.

Can you perhaps give a rough estimate of how long to would take, and how the time will be (roughly) distributed over these four headlines A very rough estimate is fine...

Upgrade/install WCS components : _ % of time

Upgrade/migrate DB2 schema and data: _ % of time

Upgrade and fix front end issues: _ % of time

"Other tasks": _ %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade/install WCS components : 1.5 day

Upgrade/migrate DB2 schema and data:  % of time (no need to migrate DB2 schema) just publish Aurora and copy Aurora store JSP's to your Madisons Store. you should do Madisons to Aurora migration .

Upgrade and fix front end issues: _ % of time it's [depend on your customization.]

Thanks